AMPL - integrand following max{...} has invalid type
In the code snippet T, P, C are sets and x, z are binary variables.
Equipa {t in T, p in P}:
    max{c in C} x[p,t,c] = z[p,t];

I get the error:
integrand following max{...} has invalid type
How can I rewrite this in a way that works?

That error does not occur in AMPL, but occurs in GLPK which only implements a subset of AMPL syntax.
The following model:
set T := 1..10;
set P := 1..10;
set C := 1..10;

var x{P,T,C};
var z{P,T};

Equipa {t in T, p in P}:
    max{c in C} x[p,t,c] = z[p,t];

produces the error when solved via glpsol:
glpsol --model test.run
GLPSOL--GLPK LP/MIP Solver 5.0
Parameter(s) specified in the command line:
 --model test.run
Reading model section from test.run...
test.run:9: integrand following max{...} has invalid type
Context: ...quipa { t in T , p in P } : max { c in C } x [ p , t , c ] =
MathProg model processing error

The issue is that GLPK does not accept max of variables, only max of parameters. Replacing var x{P,T,C}; by param x{P,T,C} default 0; fixes the error.
In AMPL having a max of a set of variables is accepted and automatically linearized if the solvers do not support max natively.
